# Plot with discrete X-axis range in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, range, subset, matlab-figure

I have a numeric array called `samples` with **size [1 250]**.
I want to plot it such that points in range `[100 110]` and `[200 350]` are not displayed on the plot.

Comment: Don't plot them or replace them with `NaN`s

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See comments inside the code:

```
function q47150844
%% Omit Y values in a certain range:
% Generate some data:
samples = randi(500,1,250);
% Choose valid points:
valid = (samples < 100) | (samples > 110 & samples < 200) | (samples > 350);
% Set invalid points to NaN:
samp_proc = samples; samp_proc(~valid) = NaN;
% Plot the remaining data:
figure(); plot(samp_proc,'.'); hold on;
% Plot the rejection limits for verification:
plot([0 250],[100 100],':r',[0 250],[110 110],':r',...
     [0 250],[200 200],':r',[0 250],[350 350],':r');
%% Omit X values in a certain range:
xrange = 1:numel(samples);
valid = (xrange < 100) | (xrange > 110 & xrange < 200) | (xrange > 350);
xrange(~valid) = NaN;
figure(); plot(xrange,samples,'.'); hold on;
plot([100 100],ylim,':r',[110 110],ylim,':r',...
     [200 200],ylim,':r',[350 350],ylim,':r');
```

Results:

[image: Y-value removal]

[image: X-value removal]